# French characters display issue using UTF8 encoding

Tags: c#, csv, utf-8

I am writing a web scraping application that writes data into a CSV file dynamically with UTF8 encoding.  The french characters do not get displayed properly. If I save the generated CSV output as a CSV file, then open the CSV file in notepad first without making any changes and then when I reopen the file in Excel, the charaters are shown properly.  Manual intervention of saving first with Notepad is not an option for this dynamic solution.  Below is the sample code.  Any ideas how to fix this?  Thanks.

```
public System.IO.Stream dsCSV(string url, string langID)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb1 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        if (langID.Equals(Fr))
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureFr;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureFr;
            processCSVData(sb1, url);
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureEn;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureEn;
            processCSVData(sb1, url);
        }
        byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb1.ToString());
        return new MemoryStream(resultBytes);
    }

    public System.Text.StringBuilder processCSVData(System.Text.StringBuilder sb1, string url)
    {

            sb1.Append("Sociétés par portefeuille ministériel");
            sb1.Append(",");
            sb1.Append("Actif total");
            sb1.Append(",");
            sb1.Append("Passif à court terme");
            sb1.Append(",");
            sb1.Append("Passif à long terme");
            sb1.Append(",");
            sb1.Append("Avoir");
            sb1.Append(",");
            sb1.Append("Emploi");
            sb1.Append("\n");


        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/csv";
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Resources.CcSe.filename + ".csv");
        return sb1;
    }
```

Comment: What is this, Java? Just guessing...

Comment: That is certainly not Java. Probably C#. @Raj fix your tags.

Answer (score 1):

Versions of Excel (prior to 2013) require a BOM at the start of the UTF-8 file to recognise the encoding.  Notepad will be adding the BOM to your file which is why you see files it has modified being opened by Excel.

Add the byte sequence `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF` to the start of the CSV file you are generating.